# Xcode - didSelectRowAtIndexPath doesn't run

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

i have this simple code in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *selected = @"test";
    NSLog(@"You choose: %@", selected);
}
```

This is my **ViewController.h**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UITableView *tableData;
}

@end
```

When i run the App, the TableView display all data, but then i cliked in a cell the method above doesn't run (?)

[image]

Comment: Check that the table view's delegate is properly set. This is different from the datasource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the delegate for the tableview in your storyboard, select your table view right click and drag to the view controller and you should see the option to set dataSource delegate and tableviewdelegate - I forget the exact names.

Answer (score 0):

e.g.:    thats part of my code, but should show you what you need to do. You need to hand over the data somewhere.

```
NSDictionary *oneDict = [_noteBookArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *touchString = [oneDict objectForKey:@"value"];
NSString *dateString = [oneDict objectForKey:@"timestamp"];
```

//call the method who does it

```
    [_noteBookViewController setContentAndTimeStampWith:touchString and:dateString];
```

//set the present View Controller active (the controller who contains the values)

```
 [self presentViewController:_noteBookViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

method from the notebookviewcontroller

```
- (void)setContentAndTimeStampWith:(NSString *)contentString and:(NSString *)timeStampString
{_textInputView.text = contentString;
_timeStampString = timeStampString;}
```

got it?